# ImportError: No module named numpy on Ubuntu after Numpy Installation

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, ubuntu, installation

I am trying to use numpy on Ubuntu 16.04. I have python 2.7.12 installed. I have tried:

```
sudo apt install python-numpy

sudo apt autoremove 

dpkg -L python-numpy
```

Here is an excerpt of the output:

```
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/python2.7
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy-1.11.0.egg-info
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy-1.11.0.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy-1.11.0.egg-info/PKG-INFO
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy-1.11.0.egg-info/top_level.txt
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/shape_base.py
```

However, when I try to run a simple file such as this, I still get the same error.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3])

python test2.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 3, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named numpy
```

Is there anything left that I need to check for? Thanks!

Comment: try sudo apt-get install python-numpy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try from the command line,

```
pip install numpy --user
```

then you should be able to `import numpy` in a new python session.

but to really handle this sorta thing well, you should create sandboxed environments for projects where you specify not the packages and even the python version used. that way you don't accidentally install a package in the wrong path, or have it installed for python2 but not have it available if your default python is python3, that sorta thing.

if you download anaconda, you get a great way to manage all that:
https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html

otherwise you can use `venv` (stands for 'virtual environment'): https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

UPDATE: and now [pipenv](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), from the maker of Requests (Kenneth Reitz)

Comment: It worked! Thank you! I will accept your answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

**For Ubuntu**

Try

```py
sudo apt install python-numpy
```

Then try the command

```py
python -c "import numpy; print(numpy.__version__)"
```

It will show you the installed numpy version